# sort df but exclude first 2 columns from sort

Tags: pandas, sorting

I want to sort a df but I want to exclude the first 2 columns from the sort.

I am able to successfully sort whilst excluding the first 1 column, but I want to update the code below to exclude the first 2 columns.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
Cars = {'Dimensions': [0.48,0.44,0.4,0.6],
        'Price': [0.3,0.25,0.74,0.5],
        'Year': [0.41,0.38,0.64,0.65],
        'Range': [0.95,0.98,0.24,0.42],
        'Height': [0.75,0.88,0.84,0.95],
        }

df = DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Dimensions', 'Price','Year', 'Range', 'Height'], 
               index=['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'])

s = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[:, ((-s[1:]).argsort() + 1).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0)]
```

I thought this would work but it does not

```
s = df.iloc[0:1]
df = df.iloc[:, ((-s[1:]).argsort() + 1).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0)]
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argsort'
```

Expect output:

```
                Dimensions  Price  Range  Height  Year  
Honda Civic           0.48   0.30   0.95    0.75  0.41  
Toyota Corolla        0.44   0.25   0.98    0.88  0.38 
Ford Focus            0.40   0.74   0.24    0.84  0.64  
Audi A4               0.60   0.50   0.42    0.95  0.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is instead `Series` indexing return one row `DataFrame`, and because `argsort` is implemented yet only for `Series` error is raised:

```
s = df.iloc[0:1]
print (s)
             Dimensions  Price  Year  Range  Height
Honda Civic        0.48    0.3  0.41   0.95    0.75
```

For exclude first 2 columns add helper `Series` for first 2 columns filled by `0,1` and also add `s[2:]` for omit first 2 index values:

```
s = df.iloc[0]

new = pd.Series([0,1], index=df.columns[:2])
df = df.iloc[:, new.append( ((-s[2:]).argsort() + 2))]
print (df)
                Dimensions  Price  Range  Height  Year
Honda Civic           0.48   0.30   0.95    0.75  0.41
Toyota Corolla        0.44   0.25   0.98    0.88  0.38
Ford Focus            0.40   0.74   0.24    0.84  0.64
Audi A4               0.60   0.50   0.42    0.95  0.65
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. There was no way I was going to solve this without your help.